# Reactive Extensions: Throttle/Sample with varying interval

Tags: .net, system.reactive

I have an `IObservable` that produces values at random intervals and I want to throttle this sequence. One thing I have found out is that the `Throttle` operator's definition of "throttling" is not the same as mine.

`Throttle` only produces values after the specified interval elapses **with silence** (it produces the last value seen). I thought throttling would mean producing values at the specified interval (unless there's silence, of course).

Say, I expected `Observable.Interval(100).Select((_,i) => i).Throttle(200)` to produce (modulo any performance/timing issues) the even numbers, since I am throttling it to "half-speed". However that sequence produces no value at all, because there's never a period of silence of length 200.

So, I discovered that `Sample` actually does the "throttling" behavior I want. `Observable.Interval(100).Select((_,i) => i).Sample(200)` produces (again, modulo any performance/timing issues) the sequence of even numbers.

However, I have one other problem: the interval varies, depending on the last "sampled" value. What I want is to write an operator that looks like this:

```
public static IObservable<T> Sample<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Func<T, TimeSpan> intervalSelector);
```

The `intervalSelector` parameter produces the interval for the next sample, and the first sample... is either taken at the first value or from an additional parameter, I don't care.

I tried writing this but I ended up with a large convoluted construction that did not work quite right. My question is, can I build this using the existing operators (aka, with a one-liner)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many hours later, and with some sleep on it, I got it.

```
public static IObservable<T> Sample<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Func<T, TimeSpan> intervalSelector)
{
    return source.TimeInterval()
                 .Scan(Tuple.Create(TimeSpan.Zero, false, default(T)), (acc, v) =>
                 {
                     if(v.Interval >= acc.Item1)
                     {
                         return Tuple.Create(intervalSelector(v.Value), true, v.Value);
                     }
                     return Tuple.Create(acc.Item1 - v.Interval, false, v.Value);
                 })
                 .Where(t => t.Item2)
                 .Select(x => x.Item3);
}
```

This works as I want: each time it produces a value `x`, it stops producing values until `intervalSelector(x)` time passes.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't what you're looking [for Observable.BufferWithTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff707707(v=VS.92).aspx)?

Comment: BufferWithTime suffers from the same defect as the others: the time interval is constant. I need to compute how long to wait to take the next sample from the last sampled value. I'll see if I can draw a marble diagram for this...

Answer (score 0):

I did it in another way and I would like to share it with anyone who is useful.

```
var random = new Random();
Observable.Return(Unit.Default)
            .SelectMany(_ => Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(random.Next(1, 6))))
            .TimeInterval()
            .Do(value => Console.WriteLine(value))
            .Repeat()
            .Subscribe();
```